# Bootstrap 4 .custom-select class showing two overlapping arrow styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've encountered an issue when using the .custom-select class in Bootstrap-4. It seems to show two arrow styles that are overlapping:

[image]

```css
.custom-select {
  position: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radiu: 2.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
          <select class="custom-select">
          <option selected>Choose One...</option>
          <option value="1">Boots</option>
          <option value="2">Shoes</option>
          <option value="3">Feet</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

The additional CSS I added was to just match other forms I have been using, the problem still persists without any of those custom styles.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you havr more styles because i see no tow arrow only one

Comment: Looks perfect here

Comment: No there is no other styles relating to the select class.

Comment: can you specify on which browser you have issue, your code snippet seems to works perfectly fine

Comment: I'm using the firefox but have the same problem on chrome. I'm using local copies of the bootstrap files and precompling with sass - it seems the bootstrap CDN makes the form style correctly but using my own local files this issue is still there leading me to beilive it was my files that had the issue. I re-installed all of the bootstrap files and still have the same issue - I tried without any of my custom css/scss also but still had the same problem. No idea where this is coming from

Answer (score 20):

You're most likely missing the vendor prefix classes for the `.custom-select` element, so you'll need to setup [Autoprefixer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/build-tools/#autoprefixer) to get this working.

Autoprefixer will add

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
```

Comment: This helped me. Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue when compiling the bootstrap SCSS with webpack in my ejected create-react-app application.

One [article I read](https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760) said to include

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  include: paths.appSrc,
  loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
}
```

in the webpack configuration's `module.rules`. Similar documentation can be found on [the sass-loader Github page](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader).

What solved the issue was the webpack config given on [the bootstrap webpack page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/):

```
{
  test: /\.(scss)$/,
  use: [
    // inject CSS to page
    { loader: 'style-loader' },

    // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
    { loader: 'css-loader' },

    // Run post css actions
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        plugins: function () { // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
          return [
            require('precss'),
            require('autoprefixer')
          ];
        }
      }
    },
    // compiles Sass to CSS
    { loader: 'sass-loader' }
  ]
},
```

I'm not sure if you're using webpack, but this might help someone.

Comment: This needs the property `ident: "postcss"` inside the options object to work now. Otherwise it will look for a missing _postcss.config.js_.

Answer (score 0):

For Ember.js users, simply install Autoprefixer to fix this issue:

```
ember install ember-cli-autoprefixer
```

Docs: https://github.com/kimroen/ember-cli-autoprefixer

Thanks @Tom for the hint!